# How to make a Square Frame Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-framelayout

I tried making custom MySquareFrame class by extending android.widget.FrameLayout and override onMeasure mehtod by passing custom width and height.

```
public class MySquareFrame extends FrameLayout {

public MySquareFrame(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MySquareFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MySquareFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public MySquareFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
}
```

and used this in xml like this

```
<com.example.akash.view.MySquareFrame
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background3">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/fuel_meter"
    android:rotation="120"
    />
<com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
    android:id="@+id/seekArc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    seekarc:max="120"
    android:padding="70dp"
    seekarc:rotation="180"
    seekarc:startAngle="30"
    seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
    seekarc:touchInside="false"
    seekarc:clockwise="false"
    seekarc:thumb="@drawable/nob" />
</com.example.akash.view.MySquareFrame>
```

and what I get 
[image: Landscape view]

So I want MySquareFrame class to look Square in xml. Please help..

--------------------UPDATED-------------------------

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
```

this helped me to get square frame according to screen dimension.

Comment: use display metrics to get the width of the display and set the height same as width in the code so that it will appear square

Comment: Y.thanks. It worked.

Comment: Update your code "stating `updated` " it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see implementation of [`SquareFrameLayout`](https://github.com/android/animation-samples/blob/master/ActivitySceneTransitionBasic/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/activityscenetransitionbasic/SquareFrameLayout.java#L26) from android developers website:

```
    

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthSize == 0 && heightSize == 0) {
            // If there are no constraints on size, let FrameLayout measure
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            // Now use the smallest of the measured dimensions for both dimensions
            final int minSize = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
            setMeasuredDimension(minSize, minSize);
            return;
        }

        final int size;
        if (widthSize == 0 || heightSize == 0) {
            // If one of the dimensions has no restriction on size, set both dimensions to be the
            // on that does
            size = Math.max(widthSize, heightSize);
        } else {
            // Both dimensions have restrictions on size, set both dimensions to be the
            // smallest of the two
            size = Math.min(widthSize, heightSize);
        }

        final int newMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(newMeasureSpec, newMeasureSpec);
    }
```

Comment: Link is 404. The file is on GitHub now: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActivitySceneTransitionBasic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/activityscenetransitionbasic/SquareFrameLayout.java

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SquareLayout](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/SquareLayout), an **Android Library** which provides a wrapper class for different Layouts, rendering them Squared dimensioned without losing any core functionalities.

The **dimensions are calculated just before the Layout is rendered**, hence there is no re-rendering or anything as such to adjust once the View is obtained.

To use the Library, add this to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.kaushikthedeveloper:squarelayout:0.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a much "reduced" solution for this. Create your own OneOneFrameLayout as follows and then just add this FrameLayout to your xml:

```
public class OneOneFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

public OneOneFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public OneOneFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public OneOneFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public OneOneFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr, @StyleRes int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int snHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int snHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(snHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, snHeightSpec);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of wanting square views using `GridLayoutManager`, Koopa has a good answer but you already have the `widthMeasureSpec`.
The width is all that matters, then get the height to match the width:

```
package com.my.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); //<-- Width + Width...
    }
}
```

Simply use it in the xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.my.package.SquareFrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    //<!--Views..-->

</com.my.package.SquareFrameLayout>
```